# How to automatically divide a div in two parts

Tags: php, html, css

The below elements are coming from a database table.

```
<div id="some_content">
  <a href="#">Data1</a><br>
  <a href="#">Data2</a><br>
  <a href="#">Data3</a><br>
  <a href="#">Data4</a><br>
  <a href="#">Data5</a><br>
</div>
```

There might a case when there are more than 50 elements, and if that happens, I don't want my page window to overflow (and scroll).

I only want two columns.

It should adjust the number of rows into one / two columns automatically.

Whenever there are more than 10 elements, I want two columns in the web page. Now there can be n-number of `a` elements.

If there are 50, then it should automatically adjust 25 in each column, and if 30, then 15 in each.

Comment: If there are 50 elements, you will have 5 columns. So I don't get your "I only want two columns" part.

Comment: And I don't understand what you actually ask... If you already use php (since you say that the values "come from a database"), then obviously you have to extend your script implementation such that it creates _two_ `<div>` cointainers instead of one (or whatever structure you like).

Answer (score 1):

This is just simple math... Do something like:

```
$number_of_columns = count($items) > 10 ? 2 : 1; // If more then 10, 2 columns
$number_of_items_per_column = floor($items / $number_of_columns); // Floor is needed because the result can be a fraction

while( $item = mysqli_fetch_array( ... ) ) {
    if( $i === $number_of_items_per_column ) {
        echo '</div><div>'; // close column and open new one
    }
    echo $item; // yeah not exactly like this, but you get the point
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Only half the answer - he's also going to need some JavaScript to adjust the number of results displayed to keep it within the confines of the page window. Out of curiosity, what is `$++`? Typo?

Comment: @Jonathan that should be `$i++` of course ;) And I don't read his question as he wants all contents _always_ to be on screen (which will be hard, because eventually you'll have to either scroll vertically _or_ horizontally). I just read it as he wants the results to be in 2 columns when there are more then 10 results... And this semi-pseudo code should do the trick

Comment: agreed. I thought it was `$i++` but didn't want to make any foolish assumptions. Anyway I don't think the OP has done any research whatsoever so you're practically doing his work for him which makes me feel a little icky. I'd be happy leaving it at this as the solution IMHO.

Comment: yeah, he'll probably get a notice error dumped because I didn't declare the $i ;) And he needs to figure out that the breakpoint is not correct, so there's enough work left for him :p